# If Kartavirya Arjuna could invade lanka and capture Ravana, without any help from a army (according to Vayu Puran) then why couldn't Rama do the same?

Tags: ramayana, rama, arjuna, ravana, vayupurana

[image: Kartaviry Arjuna conquers lanka]

[image: Second reference]

I know that their are other versions of this story but these two screenshots are from Vayu Purana pages 101 and 104. **No version** of this story **mentioned** Kartavirya **needing to build a bridge** to get to lanka.
Also Vayu Purana doesn't even mention Kartavirya needing an army to attack lanka (other versions say he needed an army during the battle). Why did Rama need an army? Why did Rama need to build a bridge?

Comment: The precise answer is given In Bhagvat Purana , in which both the things are clearly mentioned.

Comment: There's a theory that the original Lanka in the Ramayana story was a place close to Ayodhya (i.e., not the present day Sri Lanka) or at least it's somewhere within the Indo-Gangetic plain. Later poets like Valmiki expanded on the idea and made it the present day Sri Lanka. This would explain why everyone didn't require a bridge to invade Lanka (if indeed Kartavirya-Arjuna is a true historical character).

Comment: To swift pushkar i have not read Bhagvat Purana. And this question is about Vayu Purana. The case is different. And your answer was flawed, as you said that Vayu Purana states Kartavirya defeated Ravan at the Narmada river but in reality if you look at the screenshots it says that he directly invaded lanka.

Answer (score 4):

Yes kartavirya-arjuna or Sahastra Bahu Arjuna was very powerful Kshtriya Warrior. He could have inveded Lanka alone &  defeated Ravana alone , without even need of  an army or bridge on sea to reach the lanka ,due to his powers and siddhis.

Now let's try to answer your questions from scriptures.
First of all let's see what kartavirya-arjuna was capable of and what powers he was possessing.  His powers and the boons he got from Shree Dattatreya are mentioned in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana -Skanda 9 -Chapter 15- Verses 17-18-19.**

> श्री शुक उवाच 
>  हैहयानामधिपतिरर्जुनः क्षत्रियर्षभः ।
>  दत्तं
>   नारायणांशांशमाराध्य परिकर्मभिः ॥17॥
>  बाहून् दशशतं लेभे
>   दुर्धर्षत्वमरातिषु ।
>  अव्याहतेन्द्रियौजः श्री तेजोवीर्ययशोबलम्
>   ॥18॥
>  योगेश्वरत्वमैश्वर्यं गुणा यत्राणिमादयः ।
>   चचाराव्याहतगतिर्लोकेषु पवनो यथा ॥20॥
>
> haihayānām adhipatir arjunaḥ kṣatriyarṣabhaḥ dattaḿ
>   nārāyaṇāḿśāḿśam ārādhya parikarmabhiḥ bāhūn daśa-śataḿ lebhe
>   durdharṣatvam arātiṣu avyāhatendriyaujaḥ śrī-tejo-vīrya-yaśo-balam
>   yogeśvaratvam aiśvaryaḿ guṇā yatrāṇimādayaḥ cacārāvyāhata-gatir
>   lokeṣu pavano yathā
>
> Sukadeva Gosvami said: The best of the kshatriyas, Kartaviryarjuna,
>   the King of the Haihayas, received one thousand arms by worshiping
>   Dattatreya, the plenary expansion of the Supreme Personality of
>   Godhead, Narayana. He also became undefeatable by enemies and received
>   unobstructed sensory power, beauty, influence, strength, fame and the
>   mystic power by which to achieve all the perfections of yoga, such as
>   anima and laghima. Thus having become fully opulent, he roamed all
>   over the universe without opposition, just like the wind. [**SB
>   9.15.17-19**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/15/17-19)

So he was undefeatable by enemies , was possesing enormous strength , His bodily strength i.e. was inexhaustible.Besides he was also possessing Yog-Siddhis like anima and laghima. With which he could have easily defeated Ravana of Lanka.

> **Also note that** as said in the Vayu Purana quote in your question ,kartavirya-arjuna did not invaded lanka and made Ravana captive from
>   bringing him from there but the story took place at banks of River
>   Narmada.

---

## Now Let's see what Shree  Rama Was capable of..

According to Bhagvat Purana and Valmiki Ramayana. Shree Rama was avatara of Lord Vishnu. In Rama-centric traditions of Hinduism, he is considered the Supreme Being. i.e. ParaBrahman.

As a person, Rama personifies the characteristics of an ideal person (purushottama). He was Maryada Purusottama and His kingdom was called Rama-Rajya.

---

**The very precise answer of your query  is given in this verse of Bhagvatam.**

It's said in the verse that Lord Rama did not needed any help of monkeys or didn't needed to build bridge on sea , It's all the leela of Bhagavanta. As Lord himself took this avatara upon request of god's. The power of Lord is supreme against any normal human being like 
kartavirya-arjuna ,who were killed by 
Avatara of Lord himself . When arjuna forcibly took kamadhenu from Rishi jamadagni.

> नेदं यशो रघुपतेः सुरयाच्ञयात्त 
>  लीलातनोरधिकसाम्यविमुक्तधाम्नः
>   ।
>  रक्षोवधो जलधिबन्धनमस्त्रपूगैः
>  किं तस्य शत्रुहनने कपयः सहायाः
>   ॥20॥
>
> Lord Ramacandra’s reputation for having killed Ravana with showers of
>   arrows at the request of the demigods **and for having built a bridge
>   over the ocean does not constitute the factual glory of the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead** Lord Ramacandra, whose spiritual body is
>   always engaged in various pastimes. Lord Ramacandra has no equal or
>   superior, and therefore He had no need to take help from the monkeys
>   to gain victory over Ravana. [**SB 9.11.20**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/11/20)

Simply Rama did not needed to bulid bridge nor he was requiring any help of Monkeys .

## **It was his Leela**

Comment: parashurama defeated Kartavirya Arjuna but at mata setha swyamvara lord rama was shown above lord parashurama and easily took up the bow of lord vishnu isn't it?

Comment: That's complete biasedness though. Rama was not superior to everyone. What about Vishnu himself? Shiva Purana says no one is superior to Shiva. The Devi Purana says no one is superior to the Devi's (like Durga). You can't say everything is a leela.
Also the Vayu Purana screenshots that i gave clearly stated that Kartavirya INVADED lanka. It doesn't even mention the river Narmada.

Comment: Yes you are right but the scope of Shree Ramas superiority is limited to particular chapters of Puranas in which he is glorified . Elsewhere in other chapters of same purana glorifies other gods also. The Mention of this incidence happened near the banks of narmada is mentioned in bhagvat purana.

Comment: You are also right but you are also wrong too. As this question is about the incident from the perspective of the Vayu Purana. In the Vayu Purana it is said that he invaded and conquered lanka. In the Mahabharata i read that Kartavirya had a chariot that could go anywhere he desired, so i assume that's how he attacked lanka. So i already have the answer to my question. But some people (including you) keep bringing up the counterpart of this incident in Bhagavat Puran where the incident is narrated and shown differently. I was talking about Vayu Purana where an invasion of Lanka is described.